# Вывод графики в памяти

Tags: delphi, winapi

Необходимо создать объект для вывода графики в памяти, то есть, не отображая на экране. При этом, нельзя использовать `TBitmap`, так как он не потокобезопасный. Соответственно `Win Api`. Правильно я понимаю, что никаким иным способом кроме создания не отображаемого окна это не сделаешь, или есть другие способы?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. К тому же, как у вас смешались потокобезопасность и WinAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему же - создаёте контекст `CreateCompatibleDC`, создаёте Windows bitmap - например, `CreateDIBitmap`, выбираете его в контексте и рисуете функциями GDI

[Вот пример](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24803810/createDIBitmap-in-delphi.html) с рисованием

[А здесь пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492966/createdibitmap-black-image-captured), как кусок памяти использовать в качестве данных битмапа